# Raspberry Pi install programm per image

Tags: linux, image, raspberry-pi, sd-card

i am completely new to Raspberry Pis and Linux. I installed Raspbian with noobs, by writing an image to my SD card witn win32 formatter and it worked flawlessly.

Now I want to add Jasper for voice recognition, they offer an image as well, which pretends to be the easiest way to install jasper.

At this point, I wonder, how it is working. If i write the Jasper image to my SD-card, it will be formatted and the only the Jasper image will be on the card, right? So my previously installed OS will be deleted again? Or come these images from other developers with an installed OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you write the image to the SD card, it will erase any existing image on the SD card.

You should use another SD card instead.